# JUnit Annotations not being run through

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, junit4

I have a JUnit Framework with the following annotations `@before`, `@test`, `@After`.

However when I run through my tests the `@After` Annotation is never initialised and therefore the browser doesn't close.

I've run my tests using JUnit and they all pass but the tear down step never works.

I decided to try see if any of the annotations worked, so I removed the `@before` and `@test` and the test still run and passed which suggests to me that they are not being used at all.

This is my Selenium set up:

```
public SeleniumSetup() {


    }


    @Before
    public void prepareBrowserForSelenium() throws Exception {
//      setup();
        if(DriverSingleton.getDriver() == null)
        {
            setup();    
        }
        else
        {
            driver = DriverSingleton.getDriver();
        }

    }

    public void setup() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\antho\\Automation\\WebAutomation\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        DuringTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void DuringTest() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("test has started");
        assertEquals(true, driver.getPageSource().contains("Learn Critical Automation and Dev Skills"));

        System.out.println("Learn Critical Automation and Dev Skills copy has been verified");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Automation Exercises")).click();

        assertEquals(true, driver.getPageSource().contains("Automation Practice"));
        System.out.println("Automation Practice copy has been verified");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Big page with many elements")).click();     
    }


    @After
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }
```

This is my DriverSingleton;

```
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public DriverSingleton () {

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void setDriver (WebDriver driver) {
        DriverSingleton.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

After my tests have run I expect the browser to close down.

I have added `DuringTest();` to my `@Before` class, which I suspect is the only reason the `@Test` class is getting called, without that this the `@Test` doesn't work.

Comment: Why method annotated with @ Before is non static and with @ After is static?

Answer (score 0):

**First** you shall not invoke @Test inside your setup method by calling **DuringTest()**. JUnit framework would take care of Test Method by looking **@Test annotations**. So you do not need to call it explicitly.

**Make** both @Before & @After method as non static.

Comment: I've done this but it hasn't made a difference. I've also removed the DuringTest() and now the '@test' isn't invoked either.

Answer (score 0):

If you were running a test with this code you should have seen an exception with the following message being thrown by `JUnit`:

> Method tearDown() should not be static

Method annotated with `JUnit` test annotations should always be non-static and located inside dedicated classes used exclusively for running tests. Use the following code as a base to further build your test class:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SeleniumTest {

    @Before
    public void prepareBrowserForSelenium() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running method annotated with @Before");
    }


    @Test
    public void DuringTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running main test method");
    }


    @After
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running method annotated with @After");
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Running method annotated with @Before
Running main test method
Running method annotated with @After
```

As you see everything work just fine. I would suggest reading more about JUnit testing in general and here is a good place to start:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Hi, I have removed the 'static' but it's still not calling the '@Test' or '@After' annotation.  below is my console output

Comment: '@WordPressLogin'
Feature: WordPress Login
Running method annotated with @Before

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
2 Steps (2 passed)
0m13.000s

Comment: I can't work out what the first annotation is initialised but the others aren't.

Comment: ok so I think I have found why the annotations aren't working, I think it's what you alluded to earlier in that the test's aren't actually running as JUnit tests.  When I select 'Run As' on cucumber is given as an option.  However I have looked at my libraries and JUnit 4 is there and the set up page seems to be right,  Have I missed something else in the set up?

Comment: I don't know what IDE you are using but with IntelliJ it should be quite simple to see if you are running a test or not by all the icons and text output indicating it's a test. If you could share some screenshots and attach them to your original question I could help you further.